# Compare Object value with array in dataweave?

Tags: dynamic, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Sample input 1

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "a": [
        {
          "id": 123
        }
      ],
      "a1": [],
      "a3": [],
      "a4": []
    },
    {
      "b": [
        {
          "bid": 133
        }
      ],
      "b1": [],
      "b2": []
    },
    {
      "c": [],
      "c1": [],
      "d": []
    }
  ]
}
```

sample input 2: (based on which will filter the sample input 1)

```js
[
   "d",
   "b",
   "b1",
   "a4"
]
```

by comparing the values of both the inputs

Scenario: based on the object names present in 2 input need to filter out the objects from the payload 1.

Expected final output:

```js
{
    "data": [{
        "a": [{
            "id": 123
        }],
        "a1": [],
        "a3": []
    },
    {
        "b2": []
    },
    {
        "c": [],
        "c1": []
    }]
}
```

sample code:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
---
payload.data map ((item, index) -> item - "d" - "b" - "b1" - "a4") //
 Note: This sample is working but but the values should be taken dynamically from the 2 input
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

Payload is the sample input 1 that you have typed in.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var filterList = [ "d", "b", "b1", "a4" ]
---
data: payload.data map {
    ($ -- filterList)
}
```